# CSS vertically align image and blockquote and auto width blockquote

Tags: html, css

I have a list of items which consist of an image and blockquote. I have been trying to set the images width to a set max-width. Then trying to make blockquote fit in automatically by the images side. Whilst keeping both elements vertically aligned center too.

I'M having some problems and would be thankful if someone could help. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mynameisdonald/NLCnk/)

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/180x100"></div>
    <blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas nec magna elit. Suspendisse nec enim lacus. Aenean semper ipsum in faucibus blandit. Duis auctor ornare viverra. – Person</p></blockquote>
    </li>    
    <li>
    <div><img src="http://placehold.it/146x16"></div>
    <blockquote><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas nec magna elit. Suspendisse nec enim lacus. Aenean semper ipsum in faucibus blandit. Duis auctor ornare viverra. – Person</p></blockquote>
    </li>    
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
ul li {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 30px;
}
ul li div {
    width: 200px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
ul li img {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
ul li blockquote {
    color: #999;
    float: right;
    font-style: italic;
    margin: 0;
    width: 70%;
}
ul li blockquote p {
    margin: 10px 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have removed `float`, so that it could be vertically aligned properly. Please check this http://jsfiddle.net/NLCnk/3/

Answer (score 0):

If using `flexbox` is an option for you, take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/dcsturm/ypxud/

Updated the fiddle, because I had overread the width-aspect of your request.

And if you want to learn more about this awesome technic: http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/